# Modal ocupar tela inteira

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css3

Tenho a seguinte Modal e quero que ela ocupe a tela inteira / ou maior parte da tela:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="treinamentos" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="alterarLabel" style="z-index: 1100;" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
       <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"><label for="nmTreinamento" id="nmTreinamento"></label></h4>
           </div>
       <div class="modal-body">

       <object width="640" height="390" >
            <param name="movie" id="filme"></param>
            <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></param>
            <embed id="meuid" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" fs=1
            allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always"
            width="570" height="480" align="center"></embed>
      </object>
    </div>                
</div>
```

Já tentei forçar o **width:100%**, entretanto o tamanho da modal não é alterado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basta alterar as propriedades das classes `modal-dialog` e `modal-content`, desta forma:

```
.modal-dialog {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

.modal-content {
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qgoe6gko/)

Mais informações: [Modal Full Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18522320/4843158)